# Bytearray in Python 2 is not behaving as expected

Tags: python, python-2.7, arrays

I am playing around with the bytearray type in python 2.7.3 and noticed this weird behaviour:

Passing an integer argument to its constructor creates a bytearray of size equal to the integer filled with zero bytes:

```
>>> s = bytearray(15)
>>> s
bytearray(b'\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00')
```

However, if I attempt to create a bytearray with bytes set manually by me, **the constructor seems to ignore/skip some of the bytes I create**:

```
>>> s = bytearray(b'\x34\x78\x98\xFF\xFF')
>>> s
bytearray(b'4x\x98\xff\xff')
```

***Why is this happening? Is this a bug? Or am I missing something?*** [The python documentation is not very enlightening](http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/functions.html#bytearray).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Nothing strange is happening, all the bytes are still there. Relax! :)

The confusion stems from the fact that the representation is slightly optimized: bytes whose values represent printable characters are printed as those characters. This makes them take just a single character in the output rather than four.

It's doing just what it says:

- `\x34` is the character `4`, which is why the buffer starts with a '`4`'
- `\x78` is the character `x`, which is why there's an '`x`' after the '`4`'
- `\x98\xff\xff` are all kept as-is.

Note that `len(s)` prints 5.

Epic graphical representation:

```
    +---+---+------+------+------+
s = | 4 | x | \x98 | \xff | \xff |
    +---+---+------+------+------+
```

Answer (score 1):

its doing as it is supposed to by the [docs](http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/functions.html#bytearray):

> If it is an integer, the array will have that size and will be
>   initialized with null bytes.

when you gave it 15. thats exactly what it did. so nothing strange there.

> If it is a string, you must also give the encoding (and optionally,
>   errors) parameters; bytearray() then converts the string to bytes
>   using str.encode().

when you gave it your string. you did not provide encoding or errors params, which brings default. by default `\x34` becomes `4` and `\x78` becomes `x`. `\x98` and `\xFF` do not have representations in ascii, and so stayed as bytes.